# Formato de fecha en español

Tags: sql-server

Este ejemplo me arroja `03/ene./2023`

```sql
SET language 'Español'
DECLARE @D SMALLDATETIME
SET @D=GETDATE()
SELECT FORMAT(@D,'dd/MMM/yyyy')
```

Pero se necesita `3/Ene/2023`

(el dia sin el 0 a la izquierda, sin el punto y el mes con la inicial en mayúscula)

**Hay manera de obtener esto en SQL Server usando Format?**

Comment: El formato no depende necesariamente del idioma, sino de la cultura. Podemos decir que depende del país.

Answer (score 2):

Puede que te sirva este código, de todas maneras hay un pagina llamada sqlshack, en donde salen algunos formatos.

```
declare @Existingdate datetime
Set @Existingdate=GETDATE()
Select CONVERT(varchar,@Existingdate,106) as [DD MMM YYYY]
```

Comment: Esta muy bien gracias, aunque todavia no consigo quitar el 0 a la izquierda

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un par de opciones que deberían funcionar mejor que la función FORMAT en cuanto a rendimiento.

```
SET language 'Español'
DECLARE @D SMALLDATETIME
SET @D=GETDATE()
SELECT STUFF( REPLACE( convert(VARCHAR( 11), @D, 106), ' ', '/'), 1, 2, DAY(@D)),
       CONCAT( DAY(@D), '/', LEFT( DATENAME( MM, @D), 3), '/', YEAR(@D))
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa tambien es DATENAME

```sql
SELECT (DATENAME(Day,getdate()) + ' de ' + DateName(Month, GetDate()) + ' del ' + DATENAME(Year,getdate())) [FECHA]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]